# Regex exact number of exact characters in random position

Tags: regex

For example, I have a string:

```
R-G-B-G
```

I want to know is this string contains at least 2 'G', 1 'R' and 1 'B'.
String can change it size from 1 to 11 symbols, letters can appear at random position separated by '-'.

```
3 'R' -> R-R-G-R-R-B -> match
2 'B' -> ... -> not match
1 'R' 1 'G' 1 'B' -> ... -> match
```

**Edit:**

Moving forward i need to check some more cases.

My strings consist of Sockets, Links and Colors, ex:

```
R R-R B-R-R has 6 Sockets, one 2-link, one 3-link, 5R, 1B and 0G colors.
```

User sends me a number of sockets, length of the link, and desired colors in that link, and i must tell if it has all that or not. I've built expressions to match each individual case, but i cant figure out how to put them together.

[6 sockets](https://regex101.com/r/u9jjmg/2/), [Link with size 2](https://regex101.com/r/NLSzmp/2/), [2 R colors](https://regex101.com/r/LiWO5p/1/)

All of that combined must return true because R **R-R** B-R-R, on the other hand, string: **R R R B-R-R** must be false because 2 R link is part of a 3 link B-R-R.

Or should i just run 3 separate expressions with output of previous sent as an input to the next.

Comment: What is your question? What language do you use (put it in tags)? What have you already tried?

Comment: How do any of your strings match if they don't contain 2 `G` as you specify is a requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain look-aheads `(?=...)` after the start `^` for each required letter.

F.e. for at least two 'R' and two 'G' and one 'B'.
And for a string that's 1 to 11 long.

```
^(?=(?:.*?R){2})(?=(?:.*?G){2})(?=(?:.*?B){1}).{1,11}$
```

Test [here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ad6Q9V/1)

Note that the lazy searches `*?` used in those look-aheads is just a speed optimalization.
It won't matter much in this case, since it's such a short string.

Comment: Thank you. Haven't heard about lazy quantifier, so all my previous attempts with lookaheads were not successful. So, my final form will be: 
`^(?=(?:.*?R){№,})(?=(?:.*?G){№,})(?=(?:.*?B){№,}).{1,11}$`

Comment: @PavloKotelnytskyi I changed the regex a bit since you were looking for a solution where you can set those numbers.  I would use `{№}` instead of `{№,}` though.  Since the look-aheads are merly checking for "at least", the regex engine doesn't really need to search for extra.

Comment: i've edited my original post with some more questions, maybe you'll be able to help me with them too

Comment: @PavloKotelnytskyi  A question about that.  Does that message always begins with 3 parts of `[RBG-]+` separated by spaces?  Because then you could just use 3 capture groups : `([RGB](?:[-][RGB]){0,3}) ([RGB](?:[-][RGB]){0,3}) ([RGB](?:[-][RGB]){0,3})`  and check each capture group seperatly.  Anyway, there's also this thing called backreference. f.e. `(?<!-)([RGB])(?:[-]\1)+(?!-)`, for example to find those lonely R-R. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding things here.